# How to identify necessary classes and modules of Ruby software?

Tags: ruby

Say I am writing a Ruby gem. I want to design classes and modules going to be used.

1. How to identify them?
2. Where do I need classes and where do I need modules?

Comment: A class is a type of object. A module is a construct that organizes code and provides a namespace to prevent global variable/method name clashes. Identifying what classes and modules you will need is for you to do, because it's based on your preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about one of the main design feature of the Ruby language.

Basically, you can see module as collection of tools, and class as collection of objects which are able to mix with those tools.

[Ruby faq](http://www.rootr.net/rubyfaq-8.html) says about modules :

> Modules are collections of methods and constants. They cannot generate instances.

When you want to **provide something**, you'll need a class. You can do a `MyClass.new`, you cannot with a module : `MyModule.new` won't work.

On the other hand :

> Classes may generate instances (objects), and have per-instance state (instance variables).

When you want to provide **a way of doing something**, you'll a need a module. You can do a `MyModule.doSomething(SomeParams)`. You can also do that with a class methods, but you won't be able to do some mix-in with it.

See [this faq](http://www.rootr.net/rubyfaq-8.html) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: +1 for clearly explaining the difference between the classes and modules. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is a object oriented design task, if you are really new to that I would recommend to study a book like [Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596008673.do?CMP=ILC-hf1st). I usually try to identify the core actors/concepts in the business model to discover which classes I need.
2. A basic rule is to use classes when you need to maintain some states, and modules when there is no need of maintaining states. Ruby has several uses for modules Ruby, there are several articles about this topic in the Practicing Ruby blog: [part 1](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/037-issue-8-uses-for-modules.html), [part 2](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/038-issue-9-uses-for-modules.html), [part 3](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/040-issue-10-uses-for-modules.html), [part 4](http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/gregory/043-issue-11-uses-for-modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

I use to think of Modules stricly as as behaviour capsules and Classes as state and behaviour capsules (from encapsulation).

So, if you want to encapsulate a behaviour use a module. Otherwise use a class.